# New with 4.7 - Looking for a way to specify RowDefinitions="1*, Auto, 25, 14, 20" in C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Given this Row Definition;

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="1*, Auto, 25, 14, 20">
    ...
</Grid>
```

Does anyone know how I can specify this in C# now that it's a feature of Xamarin.Forms 4.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. As per `Grid`'s documentation for [Simplify row and column definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#simplify-row-and-column-definitions):

> **In XAML**, the row and column characteristics of a Grid can be specified using a simplified syntax that avoids having to define RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition objects for each row and column.

The important part is the first 2 words - in XAML.

I dug a bit deeper into this and it turned out that indeed the feature is XAML-only, at least for now. From the official [pull request](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/10648) we can see that the functionality is being implemented via a couple of [TypeConverters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.typeconverter?view=xamarin-forms). From the [commit](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/10648/commits/bdd4ccad952d63690477b6133820f6d7e90603f7#diff-7a04726e7e86c04a674c37c963b40c56) that implements the new flow we can look into the [ColumnDefinitionCollectionTypeConverter.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/10648/commits/bdd4ccad952d63690477b6133820f6d7e90603f7#diff-7a04726e7e86c04a674c37c963b40c56) and see on the fifth line that the converter is for XAML only:

```cs
[Xaml.TypeConversion(typeof(ColumnDefinitionCollection))]
```

To sum up - no, for now the feature is XAML-only. But, because of the upcoming [MAUI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/), we are seeing more and more of the feature coming as C# extensions, so I assume it is just a matter of time to see this coming to C# as well.

You can read more about `TypeConverters` in XAML [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/typeconverters-and-xaml).